# If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\rho_k}{k}<\infty$, then does $\rho_k$ necessarily converge to $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came up with this question but don't know how to proceed further:

> Let $\{\rho_k\}$ be a positive sequence, bounded from above satisfy the condition
> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\rho_k}{k}<\infty$$
> Does it mean that $\rho_k\to0$ as $k\to\infty$?

I would very much appreciate the proof or any counterexamples.

Comment: $\rho_k=(-1)^k$

Comment: What has this to do with “exact sequences” or “sequences of functions”?

Comment: Note that if you assume that $\rho_k$ is non increasing and non-negative then the result is true.

Comment: Sorry, I need to impose several assumptions: $\rho_k$ are all positive and the sequence is bounded from above.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good counterexample:

$\rho_k = 1$ if $k$ is a perfect square, $0$ otherwise.
Then
$$ \sum_{k = 1 }^\infty \frac{\rho_k}{k} = \sum_{n = 1 }^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \zeta (2)$$

You can even make a divergent series by changing the perfect square condition to a cube one:
$\rho_k = \sqrt[3]{k}$ if $k$ is a perfect cube, $0$ otherwise.

This is called in French "séries lacunaires" which basically has the same meaning as "empty series" and (thanks to @GEdgar) translates to lacunary series.

---

To answer your "new" question, just take $\rho_k = 1$ if $k$ is a perfect square, $\frac{1}{k}$ otherwise.
Then
$$ \sum_{k = 1 }^\infty \frac{\rho_k}{k} = \sum_{k \text{ not perfect square}} \frac{1}{k^2} + \sum_{n = 1 }^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} < \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} + \zeta (2) = 2 \zeta(2)$$

Basically, no matter what you try, you won't manage to find the desired convergence... The relation series <-> sequence is really complicated... The condition you impose on $\rho$ must be very strong, e.g. monotonicity

Comment: "séries lacunaires" ... in English-language mathematics called "lacunary series".

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is interesting indeed. Btw, what if $\rho_k>0$ for all $k\in\N$ and the sequence is bounded from above?

Comment: I added another example

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example. I don't expect the convergence of $\rho_k$ to $0$ but expect counterexamples like what you did.

Comment: Ok then you are on the right spot :) you can try (on your own) to find counterexample by variating the conditions, it can be "fun" :)

Comment: Otherwise you can ensure that $\rho$ is not bounded below by a positive bound. This is pretty direct!